# Calling custom form request at the Method which gets two kinds of methods GONE WRONG

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 project and I have defined this route which gets both `POST` && `GET` methods:

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'],'register', 'Auth\AuthController@register')->name('auth.register');
```

Then in the Controller:

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $method = $request->method();

        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        {
            return view('frontend.auth.register');
        }
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            // Do ...
        }
    }
```

So as you can see, I check that if the method is GET, then show a blade and it is POST, then do some process.

But as soon as I replaced `Request $request` with `RegisterRequest $request` as method argument, the GET method does not work anymore and not showing the blade at all.

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly use my own custom form request in a method that works with both methods of POST && GET?

Comment: Why not just separate the two ?

Comment: you shouldn't have a route that is responding to both HTTP methods, you should have 2 separate routes and have them both doing 2 different things, then all the problems go away and everything is separated

Answer (score 0):

`FormRequest` will validate the request data before they arrived at the controller. Since it will validate the data if don't pass the required data  that you put on the rules it will not proceed to the controller. So instead of using `FormRequest` just use the `Request` instead or just separate your POST and GET request.